# инициализация нескольких одинаковых Swiper слайдеров

Tags: javascript, swiper

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужно инициализировать некоторое количество адаптивных слайдеров Swiper на странице (инициализируется при ширине экрана < 600px), но второй слайдер не инициализируется. Я так понимаю, что инициализацию нужно поместить в forEach? Но самостоятельно пока решить проблему не удалось, буду благодарен любому ответу

```js
const slider = document.querySelector('.slider-container');

let mySwiper;

function mobileSlider() {
    if (window.innerWidth <= 600 && slider.dataset.mobile == 'false') {
        mySwiper = new Swiper(slider, {
            slidesPerView: 1,
            spaceBetween: 10,
            loop: true,
            slideClass: 'card',
        });

        slider.dataset.mobile = 'true';
    }

    if (window.innerWidth > 600) {
        slider.dataset.mobile = 'false';
        if (slider.classList.contains('swiper-container-initialized')) {
            mySwiper.destroy();
        }
    }
}

mobileSlider()

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    mobileSlider();
});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;500&display=swap');

body {
    background-color: #111;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 150px 0;
}

.card {
    padding: 30px;
    background-color: LawnGreen;
    min-height: 300px;
    color: #111;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.slider-container {
    max-width: 1200px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto 100px;
}

.swiper-button-prev,
.swiper-button-next {
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 20px 20px;
}

.slider-buttons {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

/* swiper-bullets styling */
.swiper-pagination-bullet {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    margin: 0 15px;
    background-color: tomato;
    opacity: 1;
}

.swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
    background-color: navy;
}

.swiper-button-prev,
.swiper-button-next {
    position: static;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.swiper-container {
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.slider-container {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}

.slider-container .swiper-wrapper {
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.card {
    width: 20%;
    margin-right: 2.5%;
    margin-bottom: 2.5%;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .card {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        flex-shrink: 0;
    }

    .slider-container .swiper-wrapper {
        justify-content: initial;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/swiper@7/swiper-bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper@7/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="slider-container" data-mobile="false">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="slider-container" data-mobile="false">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
const sliders = document.querySelectorAll('.collage-swiper').forEach(slider => {
    let mySwiper;
    function mobileSlider() {


    if (window.innerWidth <= 600 && slider.dataset.mobile == 'false') {
        mySwiper = new Swiper(slider, {
            slidesPerView: 1,
            spaceBetween: 20,
//            loop: false,
        });

        slider.dataset.mobile = 'true';
    }

        if (window.innerWidth > 600) {
            slider.dataset.mobile = 'false';
            if (slider.classList.contains('swiper-initialized')) {
                mySwiper.destroy();
            }
        }
    }

mobileSlider()

    window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    mobileSlider();
    });

});
```

Comment: инициализировать можно сколько угодно слайдеров через new, но не уверен что вам именно это нужно, если вам нужна адаптивность, то у свайпера есть свое событие `resize` и есть параметр `breakpoints` в котором все медиазапросы можно указать, мне кажется у вас не очень логично код организован.

Comment: Если вы используете одинаковые селекторы для нескольких слайдеров то логично делать через `document.querySelectorAll('.slider-container').forEach()`

Comment: Зачем вы используете `innerWidth` если есть `window.matchMedia` которое даже IE10 поддерживалось

Comment: @Greg-- Мои познания js минимальны, только учусь.
Мне нужно инициализировать свайпер только для мобильных устройств, про window.matchMedia почитаю, спасибо. Пытаюсь поместить код в forEach, но пока получаю ошибки

Comment: @Greg-- вроде работает, спасибо, пойду читать про window.matchMedia.
Указал в последнем блоке вариант добавления в forEach

Comment: Если вы используете функцию одинаково для нескольких элементов не желательно ее объявлять каждый раз для каждого элемента, посмотрите я написал ответ, вынес все в отдельные функции

Comment: @Greg-- спасибо, сейчас буду разбираться

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделал пример с функциями и добавил в начале код из MDN по оптимизации события ресайза, [подробнее](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event#requestanimationframe_customevent)

Проверки в коде по типу `if (slider.swiper)`это взял с [документации](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#initialize-swiper), при инициализации свайпера можно обратится к слайдеру через его HTML элемент (контейнер) соответственно если можно обратится - значит слайдер инициирован.

```js
/* Часть для оптимизации события resize взят с примера MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event#requestanimationframe_customevent
 */
(function() {
  var throttle = function(type, name, obj) {
    obj = obj || window;
    var running = false;
    var func = function() {
      if (running) {
        return;
      }
      running = true;
      requestAnimationFrame(function() {
        obj.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(name));
        running = false;
      });
    };
    obj.addEventListener(type, func);
  };

  /* init - you can init any event */
  throttle("resize", "optimizedResize");
})();

// Дальше код относящийся к вопросу
const sliders = document.querySelectorAll('.slider-container');

let mySwipers = [] // Масив со слайдерами

function sliderinit() {
  // Создаем все слайдеры
  sliders.forEach((slider, index) => {
  console.log(slider)
    if (!slider.swiper) {
      mySwipers[index] = new Swiper(slider, {
        slidesPerView: 1,
        spaceBetween: 10,
        loop: true,
        slideClass: 'card',
      })
    } else {
      return
    }
  })
}

function sliderDestroy() {
  // удаляем все слайдеры 
  sliders.forEach((slider, index) => {
    if (slider.swiper) mySwipers[index].destroy(true, true)
  })

}
function checker() {
  // >600 удаялем, в другом случа инициализируем, если до этого не инициализировали
  if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 600px)").matches) {
    // >600 удаляем слайдеры если такие есть
    sliderDestroy()
  } else {
    sliderinit()
  }
}

checker();
window.addEventListener('optimizedResize', () => {
  checker();
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;500&display=swap');
body {
  background-color: #111;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 150px 0;
}

.card {
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: LawnGreen;
  min-height: 300px;
  color: #111;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.slider-container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto 100px;
}

.swiper-button-prev,
.swiper-button-next {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 20px 20px;
}

.slider-buttons {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}


/* swiper-bullets styling */

.swiper-pagination-bullet {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 0 15px;
  background-color: tomato;
  opacity: 1;
}

.swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
  background-color: navy;
}

.swiper-button-prev,
.swiper-button-next {
  position: static;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.swiper-container {
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.slider-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

.slider-container .swiper-wrapper {
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.card {
  width: 20%;
  margin-right: 2.5%;
  margin-bottom: 2.5%;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .card {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
  }
  .slider-container .swiper-wrapper {
    justify-content: initial;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/swiper@7/swiper-bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper@7/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="slider-container" data-mobile="false">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="slider-container" data-mobile="false">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте slider-container еще один класс типа slider-container1 и инициализируйте по нему.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]